# Jupyter environment error, loading different tensorflow version than installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, version

I am using ubuntu 20.04. I created a new environment.

conda create -n tfgpu python=3.8
conda activate tfgpu
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3
jupyter notebook

Then I open a previously created .ipynb file and I try to import tensorflow.
import tensorflow as tf
tf.**version**

version is coming out to be 2.4.1
I had an installation of tensorflow 2.4.1 in my base environment. Even if it is unrelated, I uninstalled that. I checked for tf 2.4.1 in other environment too but could not find any. When I write !pip uninstall tensorflow in that notebook, it says Skipping as no tensorflow installed. When I write !pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu, it uninstalled tensorflow==2.3. And after that it was still able to import tensorflow which was 2.4.1 version. I do not understand what is happening. I can say that I once also installed tf-nightly but was in a different environment. I am thinking it is something related to path of installation or does it have anything to do with environment name. It is really annoying, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed installing jupyter notebook. I do not yet understand what was happening, but my mistake was that. The problem is resolved.